# oncheckedchanged event not working with ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: asp.net

The `OnCheckedChanged="chkCandidateNotification_CheckedChanged"` event is not getting called when I use `ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender`.
`OnCheckedChanged` works fine when `ajaxtoolkit` is not used.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCandidateNotification"  runat="server" Checked="false" 
        Text="Send Notification To Candidate" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnCheckedChanged="chkCandidateNotification_CheckedChanged"/>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlCandidateNotification" runat="server" 
       Width="798px">                    
<td>
  <asp:Label ID="lblCandidateMailTo" runat="server" Text="To" 
     class="textbox_title_normal"/>
</td>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: post complete code with your your ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender in the question

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but to no avail. For your convenience I recorded a video demonstrating my test at http://screencast.com/t/3aStqkQDxvDG. You can also test my project here https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=F8992524AEAE67E6&id=F8992524AEAE67E6%21105

Best regards,
Rumen